# Is there any specific metric or method to drop tails of TF IDF vocabulary?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, tf-idf

I have a TF IDF vocabulary I already get from gensim or tfidfvectorizer. Is there any specific metric or method to drop tails of TF IDF vocabulary?  I mean tails at Zipf diagram. How to visualize it?
I would like to see how accuracy changes when I drop number of words in vocabulary. For instance, I have vocabulary that has 175000 of words.

Comment: You have asked too many questions at once. Please edit your questions into specific question.

Answer (score 0):

These are a lot of questions, so I will try to answer them one by one. First of all, TF-IDF is a word-document matrix. So, you can use the `min_df=5` argument to filter some of the words that were mentioned less than 5 times in a document. However, I don't think that's what you wanted since you mentioned Zipf's law.

So, the following function reads the following small [dataset](http://www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/~tiago/smsspamcollection/smsspamcollection.zip) of SMS messages and gets the count of unique words in the dataset.

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.casual import TweetTokenizer
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> words = []
>>> corpus = []
>>> tknzr = TweetTokenizer()
>>> with open('SMSSpamCollection.txt', 'r') as fin:
...     for line in fin.readlines():
...         label, text = line.split('\t')
...         text = text.lower()
...         words.extend(tknzr.tokenize(text))
...         corpus.append(text)
>>>
>>> most_common = Counter(words).most_common()
>>> most_common[:10]
[('.', 5004), ('i', 2351), ('to', 2252), ('you', 2149), (',', 1942), ('?', 1540), ('a', 1447), ('!', 1388), ('the', 1338), ('...', 1219)]
```

Let's get the words ordered by their occurrence in the dataset:

```
>>> words, counts = zip(*most_common)
>>> len(words)
9232
```

> How to visualize Zipf's graph?

You can visualize the Zipf's graph using the `Counter` object. In the following code, we will visualize the most common 100 words. More than that, the graph won't be readable:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>
>>> plt.bar(words[:100], counts[:100])
>>> plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
>>> plt.show()
```

Which will produce the following graph:

[image: Zipf's Graph]

> Is there any specific metric or method to drop tails of TF IDF vocabulary?

Now, you can use the `words` list to remove some words. In the following example, I'm going to remove the least frequent 500 words when creating the `TfidfVectorizer`:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>>
>>> vec = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=words[:-500]) #removing last 500 words
>>> vec.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> # make sure everything is as expected
>>> len(vec.vocabulary_)
8732
```

As we can see, the words within the `TfidfVectorizer` is 8732 instead of the whole words which are 9232.

I've tried removing **500** least-frequent words. Now, you can do that with different numbers and test the accuracy. Hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks for answering. How did you understood that you should remove 500 of words? I mean neither 1000 nor 100, just 500. How to measure this value?

Comment: It's just a random number (as an example)... You can try different values and see the effect on the accuracy.

Comment: Or you can use the `counts` to delete words that below certain count.